# How to set an edit link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I'm using Rails 4.0.10. I have a `show` and `edit` view for a model. The `show` url is just `model/id`, and the `edit` url is `model/id/edit`. What I can't figure out is how to create a link on the `show` page that redirects to the `edit` page.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<%= link_to "edit", model_edit_path(model) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is (swap model and edit around) :

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_model_path(model) %>
```

Comment: That code's giving me the error `NameError in Models#show: undefined local variable or method 'model' for #<#<Class:0xa41b9a00>:0xacab6ec>`, any idea why?

Comment: Because the `model` variable is not set.

Comment: if in your controller's show action you have `@model = Model.find(params[:id])`, the link should be `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_model_path(@model) %>`

Answer (score 0):

The RESTful default routes are the following:

```
#index => models_path
#new   => new_model_path
#edit  => edit_model_path(:id)
#show  => model_path(:id)
```

If you want to see all your available routes, use `rake routes` in your console